# Rails undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie on rails. My rails version is `4.2.6`, simple_form_for version is `3.2.1`. I want to redirect to the new page after I validated the params is false. And I get the error message.

> undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass <%= simple_form_for
>   [:account, @station] do |f| %>
>        ...

let me show you. This is my **routes.rb**

```
namespace :account do
    resources :stations, expect: [:index]
end
```

**stations_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @lines = Line.where(line_status: 1)
    @station = Station.new
end

def create
    unless check_post_params post_params
        flash[:notice] = "miss params"

        render action: :new # not work
        # render :new # not work
        # render 'new' # not work

        # it work for me, but can I use render?
        #redirect_to '/account/stations/new'
    else
        @station = Station.new(post_params)

        if @station.save
            redirect_to '/account/lines'
        else
            flash[:notice] = 'failed'
            redirect_to 'account/stations/new'
        end
    end
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:station).permit(...)
end

def check_post_params(post_params)
    if ...
        return false
    else
        return true
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [:account, @station] do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :line_id, t('line.line_name') %>
        <%= f.input_field :line_id,
            ... %>
<% end %>
```

The original I open the URL is `http://localhost:3000/acoount/stations/new`. After I click the submit, and I want to `render :new`, it will redirect to original URL, but I found the URL become `http://localhost:3000/account/stations`. The URL's `/new` is disappear. I have guessed it's about my `routes.rb` config.

And I tried to use `rake routes` to check my routes.

```
$ rake routes
...
POST  /account/stations(.:format) account/stations#create {:expect=>:index]}
new_account_station GET  /account/stations/new(.:format) account/stations#new {:expect=>[:index]}
...
```

I tried to use `render account_stations_new_path` and `render new_account_station_path`, but still not work for me. Thanks your help.

**Edit**

I know how to modify my code. I should validate my params on my model. And then I should use redirect_to not use render. I will update my code later.

---

**Edit 2**

I modified my model.

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :line
    has_many :spot_stations

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :line_id, presence: true
    validates ....
end
```

And I modified my controller.

```
def new
    # Because this @lines did't exist when I render 'new' on the create method. So I deleted it. And I create a method on the helper.
    # @lines = Line.where(line_status: 1)
    @station = Station.new
end

def create
    @station = Station.new(post_params)

    if @station.save
        redirect_to '/account/lines'
    else
        flash[:notice] = 'failed'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I add a method for getting lines data

```
module Account::StationsHelper
    def get_lines
        @lines = Line.where(line_status: 1)
    end
end
```

I will use it on my **_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [:account, @station] do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :line_id, t('line.line_name') %>
        <%= f.input_field :line_id,
                          collection: get_lines,
                          label_method: :line_name,
                          input_html: { class: 'form-control' },
                          value_method: :id,
                          prompt: t('common.please_select') %>
    </div>
    ...
<% end %>
```

This work great for me. Thanks your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if @station.save
    redirect_to account_stations
else
    flash[:notice] = 'failed'
    render 'new'
end
```

as argument for render method you must pass `action name`, not `url`.

Comment: I think I know the problem is where. But I want to check my params first, and I want keep the params and show on the new page. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: You should provide validations in your model to check your params.

Comment: OMG. Thank you for your advice. I got it.